# how to restrict $push in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, push, mongodb-query

I am learning mongodb and wondering if can I restrict push by matching values.

For example:

```
field1 = {
 id:123,
 title:123,
 likes: [{by:1,type:'like'}, {by:2, type:'like'}]
}
```

Can I restrict push by `id` in `likes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may have already tried was the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator, but then found out it does not suit the case here as the combination of "id" and "type" can possibly vary. For instance what you don't want is the same "id" value with both types "like" and "dislike".

This is however a typical "voting" model, and the current structure is not the best one. A better model for this is as so, with the basic fields just for example:

```js
{
    "_id": 123,
    "likeCount": 2,
    "dislikeCount": 0,
    "likes": [456,789]
    "dislikes": []
}
```

Having seperate arrays is important to the atomic update process, since you cannot both [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) from an array. But more than that, as it re-enforces the logic behind keeping the "count" values, as this is useful for simple queries as sorting as opposed to calculating array length.

In order to post a "like" for a user who you don't want to duplicate in the array, the `$addToSet` operator is still not be best one despite the values now being truly unique. You want to contrain the "count" as well, so add the conditions to the query in the update instead:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "_id": 123, "likes": { "$ne": 456 } },
    { 
        "$push": { "likes": 456 },
        "$inc": { "likeCount": 1 }            
    }
)
```

That way, if the user has already voted their "like" then not only is nothing added but the "count" is kept at the correct total as well. Basically the query condition on the update was not met as there already was an element in the array matching that value. So the document does not match and nothing is updated.

That is a good approach, but we can make that better still. What if the user already posted to "dislike" and now changes their mind to "like" instead? What you really need here are "two" update statements to cover the possible conditions, and this is where the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) comes in, to handle that logic in a single request:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// match and update where a dislike is present
bulk.find({ 
    "_id": 123, 
    "likes": { "$ne": 456 },
    "dislikes": 456
}).updateOne({
    "$push": { "likes": 456 },
    "$pull": { "dislikes": 456 }
    "$inc": {
        "likeCount": 1,
        "dislikeCount": -1
    }
});

// match and update where no dislike exists
bulk.find({ 
    "_id": 123, 
    "likes": { "$ne": 456 },
    "dislikes": { "$ne": 456 }
}).updateOne({
    "$push": { "likes": 456 },
    "$inc": { "likeCount": 1 }
});

// Send requests to server and respond
bulk.execute();
```

In this case if the first statement did not match because there was no dislike then nothing would be updated, but if there was a dislike then the correct adjustments would be made.

With the second request, this one would be applied if there was nothing in the dislikes array to match and there was also not a matching item in the likes array. So this would apply for a new vote and also does not conflict with the previous statement. Despite the two statements, the upadte is only ever applied once or not at all depending on the state conditions.

That is the basic pattern for handling this kind of voting properly, as you keep lists of each vote type as well as maintaining the counts for ease of access. The "dislikes" process is pretty much just the reverse of the logic for the elements you need to check for, and removing votes has similar conditions as well.